# Html menu bar website

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

Hey I want to make a website with a frontpage just like this one: http://foreword.io/ .

I need help with the horizontal list to get it just like the one on [foreword.io](http://foreword.io/).

I want the yellow area to be stretched all the way to the sides. When I hover over a link it only marks the upper part of the square, so I want it to mark the whole square for each link.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

.h1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  top: 90px;
  width: 1585px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 350%;
  font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia;
}

u {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.fakta {
  position: absolute;
  height: 190px;
  top: 340px;
  width: 700px;
  left: 500px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  top: 600px;
  left: 100px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="h1">
  <h1>
    <u>DatabaseNavn</u>
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="fakta">
  <p>Database med ansatte <br> og avdelinger</p>
</div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="side1.html">Side1</a></li>
  <li><a href="side2.html">Side2</a></li>
  <li><a href="side3.html">Side3</a></li>
  <li><a href="side4.html">Side4</a></li>
  <li><a href="side5.html">Side5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just adding the Height option to "li a" section in the css as below:

```
li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

it will set the height of the square so the whole yellow part will change to white.

in the case of the yellow bar size and item positions:

set the width of the ul to 100% so it will use the whole available space on the browser also remove the "left"  and finally add 'position:relative', 'left:20%' and 'width:10%; to the li section.

```
li {
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
}
```

SOURCE: My head :-P

Answer (score 0):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#2b1da7103aeec07f8b53045481c63c77

For something so simple you're using `position absolute` in places where it's not needed which could be replaced with `margin`. Thus your code is fairly [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (especially with me being on a tablet right now) So I made a [simple mockup](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#2b1da7103aeec07f8b53045481c63c77) that's [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and can work for [RWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) as well if you utilize [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

I removed a lot of the unnecessary positioning. By setting the `ul` tag to `text-align center` I was able to center the anchors by telling the `li` tag to be displayed as an `inline-block`. Then I filled the width using `width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;`

How this snippet helps.

```css
body {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

.h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 350%;
  font-family: Times New Roman, Georgia;
}

u {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.fakta {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="h1">
  <h1>
    <u>DatabaseNavn</u>
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="fakta">
  <p>Database med ansatte og avdelinger</p>
</div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="side1.html">Side1</a></li>
  <li><a href="side2.html">Side2</a></li>
  <li><a href="side3.html">Side3</a></li>
  <li><a href="side4.html">Side4</a></li>
  <li><a href="side5.html">Side5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;` and you will get an horizontal list.